# Dynamically add asp:content to a page

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I have one problem. I want to setup master pages in my application. As I have too many aspx pages, I don't want to go to everypage and add asp:content tag in it. I want some dynamic way in which I can look into my page, copying it's html/other asp controls and adding it to dynamically created content template.
I know how to dynamically create content templates. But don't know whether it is possible copying aspx page's html and adding it to content template.

Let's say, In my aspx page's codebehind, on page_PreInit, I am adding following code.

```
base.AddContentTemplate("WebHeaderPH", new CompiledTemplateBuilder(new BuildTemplateMethod(this.getControl)));
```

getControl is a method which contain anything (html, text or may load a user control.)

This way, I am adding a content template dynamically.

Now my aspx page contents following code.

```
<span id="someid" runat="server">blah blah...</span>
```

Now what I want is, to get this span tag by it's id, and wrap it under asp:content. or may be in the above getControl method.

but putting this span on page, throw following error,

> Content controls have to be top-level controls in a content page or a nested master page that references a master page.

Either I have to put, **asp:content** template on the page. but If I do this, then I don't need to create contentTemplate dynamically or keep whole page blank as I am creating contentTemplate dynamically. In both cases, I have to edit all my aspx pages.

Is there a way to get page's html and add it into **contentTemplate** without any need to edit aspx page?

Comment: I don't think so, or at least not without writing a script that will edit your aspx files. Any attempt to do it with server code would anyway be a bad idea. If you have so much aspx page and don't use masterpages, then it's a design mistake, you should try to fix it using another bad idea.

Comment: In the time it took you to write this question you probably could have manually converted a dozen files or so. If you have hundreds or thousands of pages, consider writing a custom conversion tool, but do NOT try to convert the pages at runtime.

Comment: Okay. thanks. I will manually modify all my aspx pages. Previously it was on 1.1 .net framework so there were no master page concept. We have converted it on 4.0 now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid you have to go step by step manually. It is indeed a design mistake, but it won't take you THAT long to change them all.
I've unfortunately made the same mistake as well and I fixed it by manually editing my pages.

Comment: You're my first accepted answer. I'm literally grinning here! Thank you!